# Not defined? Submit iframe from modal box post to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have

```
<iframe src="correctdata.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="330" id="correctdata"></iframe>
<div class="floatright"><a class="button bigger" onclick="window.frames['correctdata'].document.form['correct'].submit();">Submit</a></div>
```

And correctdata.php contains a form

```
<form method="post" action="correctdata.php" name="correct" id="correct"></form>
```

(There is other stuff, but I'd much rather not post it.

Yet when I press submit I get

window.frames.correctdata is undefined
[Break On This Error] window.frames.correctdata.document.form.correct.submit();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try your with "[jQuery(...)contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)"

Html:

```
<iframe src="correctdata.php" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="330" id="correctdata"></iframe>
<div class="floatright"><a class="button bigger" id="submit-iframe">Submit</a></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#submit-iframe').bind('click', function(ev) {

   ev.stopPropagation();

   var correctForm = $("#correctdata").contents().find("#correct");

   if (correctForm.length == 0)
      alert('error');
   else
      correctForm[0].submit();

   return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When the iframe is loaded, provided the content document is from the same origin, you should be able to access the content within it. You can do so by limiting the jQuery context like so:

```
$('#idInTheIframe', $('iframe')[0].contentDocument);
```

For a live example, see http://jsfiddle.net/jsumners/hSEmH/.

Comment: Yeah, I screwed up my first answer. I have replaced it with a working example.